# looping through specific columns and rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am trying to loop through columns and rows with specific perimeters. I have the rows done, but moving columns is proving to be difficult.

I have taken a picture due to not uploading the code at this time. I am looking to move down a column starting at 5 and then every 3 places till about 41, then rows starting at 5 move to the right every 2 until row 14 (about letter P).

Any help will be appreciated.

It currently prints out two lines how I want, but any more I don't know how to continue to move to the next row.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim Q As Integer
Dim r As Integer

X = 5
j = 5
k = 2
Q = 5
r = 4

For i = 1 To j
   Cells(X, k).Value = 5
   X = X + 3

   For Y = 1 To 1
      Cells(Q, r).Value = 2
      Q = Q + 3

   Next Y
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Break down your descritpions to the functions you need to accomplish your goal, like: moving whole columns, moving rows, doing this on a condition, all within the same worksheet etc. Do not ask all at once. Tell us exactly where you got stuck. Update your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The logic of code may be little weird, but it works. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

```
Sub test()
    Dim X, Y As Integer

    For j = 1 To 16
        For k = 2 To 10

            a = (Right(j / 2, 1))
            If a <> 5 Then
                Cells((k * 3) - 1, j * 2).Value = 2
            Else
                Cells((k * 3) - 1, j * 2).Value = 5
            End If
        Next
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: First, you should use [`Option Explicit`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit) and declare all your variables correctly instead of `X` and `Y` which you never use! Second, you should [never assume the worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet) and fully specify your cells. Third, can you explain what `a = (Right(j / 2, 1))` should do?

Comment: To proof if a number `j` is odd or even you should **definitely** use a mathematical function like `j Mod 2 = 0` (which is true for even numbers) instead of a text function like `right` which is **very bad practice**. `If j Mod 2 = 0 Then {even} Else {odd}` would be correct. Also the issues I mentioned above are bad practice and should be corrected. See the following guide: [VBA Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices).

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good example how to loop through cells in a specific workbook. You might change `Sheet1` to the name of your desired worksheet.

```
Option Explicit 'use this at the top of your module 
                'see: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit

Public Sub LoopThroughRowsAndCols()
    Dim iRows As Long, iCols As Long

    For iRows = 5 To 41 Step 3 'loop through rows: start at row 5 end at row 41 every third row (steps)
        For iCols = 5 To 14 Step 2 'loop through columns: start at columns 5 end at columns 14 every second column (steps)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRows, iCols).Value = "AAA" 'write somthing into the cells we looped through
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peh, the requirement is that ,every alternate filled column should be filled with "2" and the other with "5".Refer the original code provided by J8acke. a = (Right(j / 2, 1)) enable to find out whether the next column index is Odd or even, and accordingly fill 5s or 2s. and thanks for your reviews.

Comment: This answer was meant as an example *how to loop through cells with steps* correctly and following a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Cells()` because the references are absolute (counting from `A1`). Use relative positioning like in the example below.

Imaging you have a table of values starting from `C9` like so:

[image: pic]

I have several examples below how you read or write values to this table using the range `.Offset()` and `.Resize()` functions.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SOWUT()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("C9")

    Dim nrows As Long, ncols As Long
    ' Count the filled rows
    nrows = Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.count
    ' Specify the column count
    ncols = 4

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ' Go down every third row and add the values
    ' Repeat for each second column
    Dim sum As Double
    For j = 1 To ncols Step 2
        sum = 0#
        For i = 1 To nrows Step 3
            sum = sum + r.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value
        Next i
        ' Add the sum below that table values
        r.Offset(nrows, j - 1).Value = sum
    Next j

    ' Avergage all the  values in the 2nd column
    Dim ave As Double
    ave = WorksheetFunction.Average(r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(nrows, 1))
    ' Write the results into cell C5
    [C5] = ave

    ' Read in the table in a memory array
    Dim vals() As Variant
    vals = r.Resize(nrows, ncols).Value
    'Loop through all rows and columns and count values >= 5
    Dim count As Long
    count = 0
    For j = 1 To ncols
        For i = 1 To nrows
            If vals(i, j) >= 5 Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```